# How to return the column corresponding to the minimum objective function?

Tags: r

Suppose that we have a matrix where the last row presents the values of an objective functionة , for example :

```
          L_boundaries   Upper_boundaries
X1:      -0.03824382    -0.03824382
X2:      -1.14569350     1.06090257
X3:       0.90973562     2.05740218
Obj-val:  3.73230444     7.90006311
```

My question is how can i return the row that correspond to the minimum of `Obj-val`. The output for this example should be :

```
          Init_sol   

X1:      -0.03824382    
X2:      -1.14569350     
X3:       0.90973562     
Obj-val:  3.73230444
```

I'm just searching an elegant way to obtain such output.
Thank you a lot for help !

Comment: `df[df["Obj-val:",] == min(df["Obj-val:",])]` will return both if its a tie. you could use the `which.min` function similarly if you'd prefer only returned the first col in a tie

Comment: @IRTFM , i need only to return the unique column where 'Obj-val' is the minimum for the whole matrix.

Comment: @mouad2020 replace every instance of `df` in my code with the name of your matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_matrix[,my_matrix["Obj-val:",] == min(my_matrix["Obj-val:",])]

        X1:         X2:         X3:    Obj-val: 
-0.03824382 -1.14569350  0.90973562  3.73230444
```

Data:

```
my_matrix <- structure(c(-0.03824382, -1.1456935, 0.90973562, 3.73230444, 
-0.03824382, 1.06090257, 2.05740218, 7.90006311), .Dim = c(4L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("X1:", "X2:", "X3:", "Obj-val:"), c("L_boundaries", 
"Upper_boundaries")))
```